# How to get decimal ip address assigned to machine on wifi

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, ip

I want to connect to my machine on wifi network instead of using localhost. So I am trying to figure out the IP address so instead of going to `localhost:8080` I use the actual IP address. I thought this would be simple but instead I am getting a weird hex number back.  I say weird because I tried converting the first part and I got  `fe80::a0ba:ce94:bf54:f2be%13:`

And each part like `fe80` converts to a huge decimal number.  How do I get the decimal IP address like `128.10.y.54`? I seem to be getting back IPv6 stuff. Need something I can issue http request query on? I am on Windows 7 and I want to see the decimal values. Where are they? Or how could I make browser request to IP: port based on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert IPv6 to the decimal numbers you are looking for. That is a different number, the IPv4 address.

Open a command prompt, and just do IPCONFIG (not case sensitive) and hit enter. Your IP address for any adapters you have will be there, and you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

The number you're describing is an IPv6 IP address. You cannot convert an IPv6 IP address to IPv4 format.

If you're on an network that is using only IPv6, then you can't get an IPv4 IP address assigned to your wireless adapter (because there will be no DHCP server giving out IPv4 addresses).

Your IPv6 IP address should work, with a port appended as you describe, exactly like an IPv4 address.

As mentioned in the other answers, you can open a command prompt on your computer and enter "ipconfig" for a list of installed adapters and their configurations; you may find that your adapter *also* has an IPv4 address assigned to it.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 for making it clear that that _is_ an IP address, and that it may well be the sole (non-loopback) IP address for the machine (although this is unlikely in this case since FE80::/10 is link-local unicast).  But you missed noting that IPv6 addresses, unlike IPv4 addresses, must be enclosed in square brackets when used in CIS URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7, without using the command prompt

In the system tray, click the network connection icon and select Open Network and Sharing Center.

To view the IP address of a wired connection, click Local Area Connection.
To view the IP address of a wireless adapter, click Wireless Network Connection (Network Name).

Click Details... . Your IP address will appear next to "IPv4 Address".

(found at http://kb.iu.edu/data/aapa.html)